# Javascript Canvas issue: Why do my points on the canvas not correspond properly to the height of the graph?

Tags: javascript, canvas, plot, points, linegraph

I'm trying to make a line graph using the canvas that looks like a typical line graph and uses typical Cartesian coordinates like we learned in algebra;
starts with 0,0 at the bottom left, and the position x-axis is to be determined by the number of items to chart.

However, the position of the points doesn't match the input (although the shape of the graph is correct, indicating I'm doing something right).  What am I doing wrong?

I've rewritten and tweaked the formula for converting numerous times

```
function newLineGraph(parent, width, height, dataArray) {
    //this makes the element using my own code, no observable error here
    var canvas = newCanvas(parent, width, height);
    var canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var spaceBetweenEntries = width / dataArray.length;

    var largestNumber = findHighestNumber(dataArray);

    canvasContext.beginPath();
    canvasContext.moveTo(0, 0);

    var n = 0;
    while (dataArray[n]) {

        var x = spaceBetweenEntries * n;
        var y = height - dataArray[n];
        console.log("x,y", x, y);
        canvasContext.lineTo(x, y);
        n++;
    }
    canvasContext.stroke();

    return canvas;
}
```

[image: The resulting graph]

edit:  fixed the image so you can see the canvas size

The resulting graph is much smaller than the intended graph; for example
`newLineGraph("body",55,45,[1,40,10]);`
produces a graph with a small ^ shape in the corner, rather than properly starting at the bottom.  However, the console logs show `" 0 44" "18.333333333333332 5","36.666666666666664 35"` which I believe should produce a graph that fits the whole chart nicely.

Comment: Do you have any CSS that modifies the width and height of the canvas?

Comment: No, I've confirmed the height with inspect element, but thanks!

Comment: confirmed both height and width, that is

Comment: Add the code for `newCanvas()`. And make a demo that shows the problem, use https://jsfiddle.net/ or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>The first `lineTo` will always have `x` as 0 so I assume the first line isn't drawing like you intended. It is more like a `|/\` shape instead of `\/\`.
Set x like this:</s>

```
var x = spaceBetweenEntries * (n + 1);
```

**Edit**

As you can see in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oa905fpj/) your chart renders at the right points with the coordinates you posted. I implemented the `newCanvas` function like I expect it to behave. So are we missing some other code that modifies the canvas `width` and `height`?

```
function newCanvas(parent, width, height) {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  document.querySelector(parent).appendChild(canvas);
  return canvas;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want it to be zero at first, so it would just start at the left side.  The problem is that each point isn't nearly as far down as I thought it would be, for example,
newLineGraph("body",100,100,[3,10,30,100]); 
the canvas is 100px by 100px, the first entry is three, so I expect it to be very close to the bottom, however, it starts about 1/3rd from the bottom: https://i.imgur.com/d2gXZoi.png

Comment: @sheepdeets When I inspect the image the height exceeds 100 pixels, the code you posted should do the trick. I'm not sure how you set width and height in `newCanvas` function.

Comment: Thank you so much for testing it out! 

The issue was that I was using, basically, canvas.style.height = "100px" instead of canvas.height = 100

Thank you for spending your time on this!

Comment: @sheepdeets That's why I asked about the CSS, you actually set the CSS width and height with the `style` property.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was using style.width and style.height to modify the canvas height, instead of canvas.height and canvas.width